# DFS Namespace - The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: active-directory, fileserver

A few months ago, we deleted/decommissioned a server name, "DFS-SERVER02" without any issues in our infra. Still, we received notice last week that DFS Namespace "\md.domain.com\data" is not working properly. When the user tries to get that path receives the below error:

**Error code: 0x80070043
The network name cannot be found**

From the DFS console, I see the below error message:

**\md.domain.com\data: The namespace cannot be queried. The RPC server is unavailable.**

Well, I ran the following command as my troubleshooting steps:

```html
DFSDiag /TestSites /DFSPath:\\md.domain.com\data /Full

Starting TestSites...
Validating the site associations on every domain controller of the following: DFS-SERVER01
Success: The site associated with the following hostname is consistent on all accessible domain controllers: DFS-SERVER01
Validating the static site association by accessing the registry.
Success: The static site-association of the following host name is consistent with the site-association in Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS): DFS-SERVER01

Validating the site associations on every domain controller of the following: DFS-SERVER02
Error: The format of the specified computer name is invalid.
Validating the static site association by accessing the registry.
Error: The format of the specified computer name is invalid.
Error: The RPC server is unavailable.

Finished TestSites.
```

```html
DFSUtil.exe /pktinfo

Entry: \md.domain.com\data
ShortEntry: \md.domain.com\data
Expires in 0 seconds
UseCount: 1 Type:0x81 ( REFERRAL_SVC DFS )
  0:[\DFS-SERVER01\DATA] AccessStatus: 0 ( ACTIVE TARGETSET )
  1:[\DFS-SERVER02\DATA] AccessStatus: 0xc00000cc ( TARGETSET )
```

At this point, it is clear that the server "DFS-SERVER02" is missing, and it was part of the config of the DFSN. As I commented at the start, that server was deleted a few months ago. I reviewed ADSI under "CN=Dfs-Configuration,CN=System,DC=md,DC=domain, DC=com", and I saw some information there, but I cannot see anything related to the membership or ComputerReference.

I appreciate your help on this matter because I do haven't more ideas :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove orphaned namespace server by:

- going to DFS Management
- Namespaces
- add your namespace to display and click on it
- go to Namespace Server tab
- remove orphaned namespace server

Answer (score -2):

Based on the information you provided, it's clear that the issue with the DFS Namespace "*\md.domain.com\data*" not working properly is related to the deleted server "**DFS-SERVER02**" which was part of the DFS Namespace configuration. The error message you received, "The RPC server is unavailable," is indicative of the fact that the DFS Namespace is unable to contact the deleted server.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to perform the following steps:

1. Remove the deleted server from the DFS Namespace configuration:
   Since the server "DFS-SERVER02" no longer exists, it should be removed from the DFS Namespace configuration. To do this, follow these steps:
   a. Open the DFS Management Console.
   b. Navigate to the Namespaces section and find the "*\md.domain.com\data*" namespace.
   c. Check the folder targets associated with the namespace, and if "DFS-SERVER02" is listed, remove it from there.
2. Update the DFS Namespace configuration on the existing servers:
   After removing "DFS-SERVER02" from the DFS Namespace configuration, you need to ensure that the updated configuration is propagated to the remaining DFS servers. You can force this update by running the following command on one of the remaining DFS servers:

   dfsutil /clean

This command will force a refresh of the DFS metadata and ensure that the deleted server is no longer referenced.

3. Validate the DFS Namespace:
   After performing the above steps, it's essential to validate the DFS Namespace to ensure it is functioning correctly. You can run the following command:

   dfsutil /pktinfo

This command will display the current DFS referral cache. Make sure that the deleted server "DFS-SERVER02" is no longer listed in the referral cache for the namespace "*\md.domain.com\data.*"

4. Verify Active Directory Sites and Services Configuration:
   Check the Active Directory Sites and Services configuration to ensure that the site association for "**DFS-SERVER02**" has been properly removed. It's possible that there are lingering references to the deleted server in the Active Directory configuration.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the issue with the DFS Namespace. The DFS Namespace should work properly, and the error related to the deleted server should no longer appear.

Comment: Hello @Oleksandr Moroziuk 

I cannot manage any property of the DFSN from the console.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: People shoud read this answer carefully. It seems like it is generated by AI tools like `ChatGPT` or `Google Bard`